# Get multiple select values with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How can i insert a multiple select value into database with ajax. I can't grab the value to pass to controller, i'm using codeigniter. I got this error in my controller:
*** Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()***

Here is how i try:

```
<select class="form-control chosen-select" multiple name="laborat" id="laborat" required>
    <option value="" hidden></option>
    <?php 

      foreach($laboratories as $row)
      { 
         echo '<option value="'.$row->name.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
      }

    ?>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#formLabo').on('submit', function(event) {
        var selected = [];
        $('#laborat :selected').each(function() {
            selected[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url('admin/SaveFormIndicacionesLab')?>",
            data: {
                laboratorios: selected
            },

            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {}

        });
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function SaveFormIndicacionesLab()
    {
    $laboratorios = $this->input->post('laboratorios');
    foreach($laboratorios as $lab)
        {
        $save = array(
            'laboratory' => $lab
        );
        $this->model_admin->SaveFormIndicacionesLab($save);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You name the index `laboratory` in the controller, but in the view you use `laboratories`.

Additionally, when you use `foreach ($laboratorios as $lab)`, $lab is the individual item from $laboratorios. If you don't need $lab, you don't need the foreach().

There may be additional issues I'm not seeing. charlietfl mentions below the data structure passed to $.ajax may be invalid.

Comment: Data structure passed to $.ajax is also invalid which is why error shown occurs

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake when i copied the codes to stackoverflow. It stil shows the same error.   'laboratory'  => $lab, : laboratory is the field of the table.

Comment: @Diasline your edit still hasn't fixed the mix up between laboratory in the controller and laboratories in the view. After fixing that, you should also `var_dump()` some variables to see their state before they fail and work your way up the code to the source of the issue.

Comment: In the view the multi select name is laborat. In js i grab it like :  $('#laborat :selected').each(function() {
            selected[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
        });                                                                                                            i pass it in data :{laboratorios: selected}                                                                  In controller i have :  $laboratorios = $this->input->post('laboratorios');     and the i loop  $laboratorios as lab. Sorry i can't see what you mean. A code exemple would help me.

Comment: @Diasline var_dump and console log is essential to figuring out problems by understanding what the values of variables are. `var_dump($variable);` for PHP and `console.log(variable);` for Javascript. You're code has multiple issues, you'll have to walk step by step through the logic, looking at the values at each line to see if anything is not what you expect.